# NodeJS - Grunt - Is it possible to run a Grunt task in NodeJs runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

I have a small application in express.js and i want to run a Grunt task, named "build", at the client request for now but i don't know how to pass sub-task configuration to Grunt module.

```
executeTask : function (components) {
    // Other stuff
    this.grunt = require("grunt");
    components = components.join();
    var file = require(this.parentDir + "/myProjectFolder/Gruntfile.js")(this.grunt);
    this.grunt.option('target', components);
    var result = this.grunt.task.run(["build"]);

    console.log(result);

    // Other stuff
},
```

This code not spawn any error but not working, the output file is no generated.
This sub-task are executed correctly from CLI, and refer to the same Gruntfile.js

Comment: I don't think Grunt supports multiple targets like that. What's in `components`?

Comment: In components, i have a list of arguments to pass to Grunt.

Comment: Each argument is a option; if they don't have a value, set them to true. Like: `components.forEach(function (c) { grunt.option(c, true); });`. Also, about `target`: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets